# Fetch Type Eager is not working with Filter

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate with multi tenancy. Multi tenancy is implemented with a filter and discriminator column(see https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-build-a-multi-tenant-application-using-spring-boot-and-hibernate-718e16bfd456)

This means that every SQL query is extended with "... and tenant =?" in the WHERE Clause

If i load an entity, an extra select is performed for each relationship. I would like to load the entity in one SELECT and not in n + 1.  Therefore I use FetchType.EAGER for the relationsship.
This works fine without Multi tenancy and the filter.
As soon as the multitenancy filter is active, this not working and the entity manager executed n+1 selects.

Does anyone know this problem and has a tip how to solve it?
Is there better multitenancy handling?

I would like to avoid EntityGraphs (for various reasons) and HQL statements for this problem

Here is a small example https://github.com/MelleD/hibernate-filter-example

Output without filter is

```
    select
    foo0_.id as id1_1_0_,
    foo0_.tenant_id as tenant_i2_1_0_,
    bars1_.foo_id as foo_id1_2_1_,
    bar2_.id as bars_id2_2_1_,
    bar2_.id as id1_0_2_,
    bar2_.name as name2_0_2_ 
from
    foo foo0_ 
left outer join
    foo_bars bars1_ 
        on foo0_.id=bars1_.foo_id 
left outer join
    bar bar2_ 
        on bars1_.bars_id=bar2_.id 
where
    foo0_.id=?
```

Output with filter is:

```
select
    foo0_.id as id1_1_,
    foo0_.tenant_id as tenant_i2_1_ 
from
    foo foo0_ 
where
    foo0_.tenant_id = ? 
    and foo0_.id=?

select
    bars0_.foo_id as foo_id3_0_0_,
    bars0_.id as id1_0_0_,
    bars0_.id as id1_0_1_,
    bars0_.foo_id as foo_id3_0_1_,
    bars0_.name as name2_0_1_ 
from
    bar bars0_ 
where
    bars0_.foo_id=?
```

Comment: `I would like to load the entity in one SELECT and not in n + 1. Therefore I use FetchType.EAGER for the relationsship.` - This is wrong statement. You should use `JOIN FETCH` in hql to avoid n + 1 query issue. See the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#best-practices-fetching-associations)

Comment: See here https://thorben-janssen.com/entity-mappings-introduction-jpa-fetchtypes/.

Comment: Can you please add your code so others can try to understand and/or reproduce your problem

Comment: Added a example